# How can I return the values for Ajax in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the function below. How can I return the values for success, error, complete in a function?

```
function checkstatus() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "foo.json",
    beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
      console.info('in beforeSend');
      console.log(jqXHR, settings);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(" 500  data still loading"+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus +  " : " + errorThrown);
      console.info('in error');
      console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert(" complete "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
      console.info('in complete');
      console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      alert(" success "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
      console.info('in success');
      console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You don't return values. Instead you pass a callback function to your `checkstatus` function, and invoke it in the `$.ajax` callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
function checkstatus( callback ) {
   $.ajax({
    .......
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        callback(data);
    }
   });
}
//and callback
checkstatus(function (data) {    
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Is the callback() a predefined function ? where is callback() coming from here?

Comment: callback inside success function is referred from checkstatus 'callback' param, which in turn is function that returns data in checkstatus function thats called after ajax as below //and callback

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the values from a separate function with an asynchronous request because the code after the `.ajax` call (where you would return) will execute *before* the ajax callbacks.  Instead, you should create a dependency on the callback.

If the request is synchronous, you could do this:

```
function checkStatus() {
   var statuses = [];
   $.ajax(...
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          statuses.push(textStatus);
      }
   ...

   return statuses;
}
```